# React trying to attachEvents under JSDom

Tags: reactjs, jsdom

I am trying to test my React (for the browser) code in what I think is an entirely conventional way: Mocha as the test-runner, JSDom to simulate the browser, Enzyme to check the results.

My problem is this: whenever I manually set the focus on a component, React throws an exception.  The problem is [deep inside React](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/packages/react-dom/src/events/plugins/LegacyChangeEventPlugin.js#L140):

```
 activeElement.attachEvent('onpropertychange', handlePropertyChange);
```

The active element is set, but as a JSDom `HTMLInputElement`, it does not have an `attachEvent`.  I have found if I hacked the file `node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/generated/HTMLInputElement.js` to give that class empty methods named `attachEvent` and `detachEvent`, the exception goes away.

But clearly, that is not the right solution.

The comments on the function, and some fragmentary information I have found elsewhere, suggests this is a shim meant for antique versions of IE, not JSDom at all.  The function involved, `startWatchingForValueChange` is only invoked if the flag `isInputEventSupported` is not set, and setting it requires another `canUseDOM` to be set.  Forcibly setting either of those flags causes other problems.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Typing up this question, I figured it out.

As the testing system was set up, when I initialized JSDom, I also set a global `afterEach()` to reset the contents of the DOM after each test.  This did not directly create a problem, but it did mean the order of initialization was necessarily like this:

1. React
2. Mocha
3. JSDom

So when React was initialized, it looked around and saw no working DOM, and figured, "Damn, I must be running on IE or something."  After that, it was all down-hill.

So I confidently restructured it like this:

1. JSDom
2. React
3. Mocha

And that... did nothing.

Then I realized the problem was, I was doing this:

```
import { JSDOM } from "jsdom";
import Enzyme from "enzyme";
import Adapter from "enzyme-adapter-react-16";

global.jsdom = initDom();
...
```

React was actually initializing itself when it was imported — by the import of Enzyme!

So I confidently rewrote it like this:

```
import { JSDOM } from "jsdom";
global.jsdom = initDom();

import Enzyme from "enzyme";
import Adapter from "enzyme-adapter-react-16";
```

And *that*... did nothing.

Because the `import` statement effectively gets hoisted to the top of the file.

So I confidently rewrote it like this:

```
import { JSDOM } from "jsdom";
let jsdom = new JSDOM("");
...
const Enzyme = require("enzyme");
const Adapter = require("enzyme-adapter-react-16");
```

And that... fixed it.

Comment: Wow, I was having the exact same problem and was banging my head against the wall for I don't know how long. Thanks for this anwer, it works perfectly!!

Comment: I had a similar issue when using the [`setup-env`](https://github.com/3rd-Eden/setup-env) package. It requires/initializes both `babel/register` and `jsdom`, in this order, which cause `react-dom` to try to check the environment before the DOM exists. Swapping its steps fixed it.